# Generating contrast matrix for limma in loop

Tags: limma, loop

I am trying to generate contrast matrix for different conditions using **for** loop.

```
cluster_len <- 3
req_contrasts <- c()

for (m in 1:cluster_len) {
  for (n in 1:cluster_len) {
    if (n > m) {
      req_contrasts <- c(req_contrasts, (paste0(paste0("Group", n), "-", paste0("Group", m))))
  
    }
  }
}
```

req_contrasts returns
`"Group2-Group1" "Group3-Group1" "Group3-Group2"`

The contrast that needs to be passed is
`"Group2-Group1","Group3-Group1","Group3-Group2"`

I have tried the following code to combine each string and form a single vector

```
# To separate each condition by a double quote and comma
temp_1 <- paste0(req_contrasts, collapse='","', sep="")
temp_1
[1] "Group2-Group1\",\"Group3-Group1\",\"Group3-Group2"
# To remove the escape character
temp_2 <- gsub("\\", "", temp_1, fixed = TRUE)
temp_2
[1] "Group2-Group1\",\"Group3-Group1\",\"Group3-Group2"
```

This does not work

```
contrast.matrix <- makeContrasts(temp_2, levels=design_mat)
Error in parse(text = ej) : <text>:1:14: unexpected string constant
1: Group2-Group1","
^
```

Limma throws the following error in presence of escape character. I am assuming it is because it considers that the string is yet to end.

Following input works

```
contrast.matrix_2 <- makeContrasts("Group2-Group1", "Group3-Group1", "Group3-Group2",                 levels=design_mat)
```

In my analysis the number of clusters to be analysed is 16. Hence, the contrast conditions cannot be generated manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this snippet a while back to generate all pairwise contrasts:

```r
make_all_contrasts <- function (group, delim="_vs_"){
  
  suppressMessages(require(limma))
  
  #/ ensure that group levels are unique
  group <- sort(unique(as.character(group)))
  
  #/ make all combinations
  cb   <- combn(group, 2, FUN = function(x){paste0(x[1], "-", x[2])})

  #/ make contrasts
  contrasts<- limma::makeContrasts(contrasts=cb, levels=group)
  colnames(contrasts) <- gsub("-", delim, colnames(contrasts))
  
  return(contrasts)
}
```

Assuming three contrasts this will create a limma-like contrast matrix with all possible pairs:

```
make_all_contrasts(group=c("groupA", "groupB", "groupC"), delim="_vs_")

        Contrasts
Levels   groupA_vs_groupB groupA_vs_groupC groupB_vs_groupC
  groupA                1                1                0
  groupB               -1                0                1
  groupC                0               -1               -1
```

Comment: You can provide a function on `combn` to make the code easier to read: `combn(group, 2, FUN = function(x){paste0(x[1], "-", x[2])})` and skip an `unlist` and a `lapply` call.

Comment: Cool, I did not know that, thanks!